# how to stop php server in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

In Atom how do you stop php server from running?  The doc's say:

```
php-server:stop
```

so I went to a terminal, cd to the root for the server and issued the command.  It said command not found

Answer (score 0):

there's an atom palette ctrl-shift-p you issue the command there.